# Windows 8 boot menu entries of ubuntu on ESP

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

So, I have a hp pavilion with Windows 8 pre-installed OS on it. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in UEFI mode with secure boot disabled and then reloaded GRUB through Windows so that every time I boot I see the GRUB menu.

Everything works correctly, however when I press F9 during boot-up I see multiple boot menu entries (10 so far) of the Ubuntu OS and a single entry of OS boot manager in an order like so:

```
ubuntu, OS boot manager, ubuntu, ubuntu, ...
```

Just after installation of Ubuntu, there was only one entry:

```
ubuntu, OS boot manager
```

Now, every time I press F9 a new entry appears.

Is there some way I can change these boot menu entries so that there is only one boot menu entry of Ubuntu ?

EXTRA INFO: I tried easyBCD and it didn't work. It shows that there are duplicate entries of internal hard drive, but when I attempt to delete it from easyBCD, they still shows up on the next boot.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) to delete not needed boot entries. Boot entries from NVRAM are not the same as boot entries/loaders specified in Windows BCD.

To delete - click on entry, right-click and select "delete selected object".

HP have not implemented UEFI very well I think. Is it one of these implementations where Windows boot manager is set as default and restored every time by firmware if not first(default) in NVRAM ?

Comment: This happens on my HP laptop as well with Windows 10 so sounds reasonable